# accessing a struct level reference in closure

Tags: rust, closures

We have a struct where we are trying to store the redis connection pool

```
struct RedisAuth {
    #[allow(dead_code)]
    configuration: Conf
    redis_pool: r2d2_pool::R2D2Pool
    
}
```

Now we have to implement trait which has closure function (this is a template that we need to follow to provide proper implementation)

```
impl Plugin for RedisAuth {
    type Config = Conf;

    async fn new(init: PluginInit<Self::Config>) -> Result<Self, BoxError> {
        tracing::info!("{}", init.config.message);
        let redis_pool = r2d2_pool::connect().unwrap();       
        Ok(RedisAuth { configuration: init.config, redis_pool: redis_pool})
    }

    fn supergraph_service(
        &self,
        service: supergraph::BoxService,
    ) -> supergraph::BoxService {
        
        ServiceBuilder::new()
                    .checkpoint(|request : supergraph::Request|  {
                        let operation_name = &request.supergraph_request.body().operation_name;
                        let pool = self.redis_pool;
                        // Do some async call here to auth, and decide if to continue or not.
                        Ok(ControlFlow::Continue(request))
                    })
                    .buffered()
                    .service(service)
                    .boxed()
    }
}
```

In the checkpoint function when we are accessing the pool from self reference we are getting this error .

**borrowed data escapes outside of associated function
`self` escapes the associated function body here.**

We do not want to initialize the pool again and again and want to use that inside the closure . Is there any workaround or refectoring that can be done to mitigate the solution . I cannot change the closure signature .

Comment: Did you try adding `move` at the beginning of a closure?

Comment: sorry I am a novice in rust ....
Does move clone the entire object again. Will appreciate some hints

Comment: `move` won't clone. All clones in rust are explicit. I've written more detailed explanation in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Closures capture by reference by default. It means that this closure has a reference to self (in your pool variable). You then return that closure from the function. Here rust has problem, as you try to return something that holds a lifetime of &self but function signature prevents that. So you must `move` ownership of pool into your closure.

Now I see that simply adding move keyword (which will make capture variables by move) will not be enough, as you would then move out of self, which is another problem. Try wrapping `redis_pool` in some kind of a shared reference, like `Rc` or `Arc`. And then simply clone this reference and pass ownership of it to the closure.

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;

struct RedisAuth {
    #[allow(dead_code)]
    configuration: Conf
    redis_pool: Arc<r2d2_pool::R2D2Pool>
    
}

impl Plugin for RedisAuth {
    type Config = Conf;

    async fn new(init: PluginInit<Self::Config>) -> Result<Self, BoxError> {
        tracing::info!("{}", init.config.message);
        let redis_pool = r2d2_pool::connect().unwrap();
        let redis_pool = Arc::new(redis_pool)
        Ok(RedisAuth { configuration: init.config, redis_pool: redis_pool})
    }

    fn supergraph_service(
        &self,
        service: supergraph::BoxService,
    ) -> supergraph::BoxService {
        
        let pool = Arc::clone(&self.redis_pool);
        ServiceBuilder::new()
                    .checkpoint(move |request : supergraph::Request|  {
                        let operation_name = &request.supergraph_request.body().operation_name;
                        // now you can use pool here
                        // Do some async call here to auth, and decide if to continue or not.
                        Ok(ControlFlow::Continue(request))
                    })
                    .buffered()
                    .service(service)
                    .boxed()
    }
}
```

EDIT. Added example usage of `Arc`.

Comment: Thanks Aleksander for help. 
Pardon my ignorance but how I can have a shared reference. Rust is totally new to me

Comment: Not able to figure out

Comment: @GJoshi If you are that new, I would strongly recommend reading [The Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/). It has a chapter on smart pointers, but I wold recommend reading it all. Rust is very *different* from other languages you might be familiar with, and it takes a while to be comfortable with it. This book is a great starting resource.

Comment: @GJoshi I edited my answer to include example usage of `Arc`. I believe it should work. If you do not need to pass this closure to another thread you could just use `Rc` instead.

Comment: thanks Aleksander. Now it is giving a different error.

closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `pool`, which is owned by the current function.

Since the pool is defined outside the closure.
Thanks again for all the help

Comment: @GJoshi That's why you have to add `move` keyword to the closure. You didn't do that, did you? If you did, then I don't know what causes this problem.

Comment: Sorry Aleksander my bad. Thanks a lot .

Comment: Will definately go through the book